Image reloads unnecessarily while navigating back to previous page
I have two pages in my Flutter app: a NewsTile page that displays a list of news tiles, and a ReadDetails page that shows the full details of a selected news item. Each NewsTile contains a small image of the news, while the ReadDetails page shows a larger version of the same image.
I'm using Hero animations to transition between the NewsTile and the ReadDetails pages. The transition works perfectly when navigating forward. However, when I navigate back using either Get.back() (from GetX) or Navigator.pop(context), the following issue occurs:

All the images in the NewsTile list are reloaded, except for the one that was involved in the Hero animation (the tile that the user clicked on to navigate to the details page). That image stays in its previous state and doesn't refresh.


Home Page
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var dataCtrl = Get.find<DataController>();
    var ctrl = Get.find<MyController>();
    var dummyData = [NewsList(newsData: dataCtrl.dummyNewsData)];
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerTop,
      floatingActionButton: const GoToTop(),
      body: Obx(
        () {
          var topStories = dataCtrl.isDataLoaded.value
              ? dataCtrl.topStories.value.data!.newsList!
              : dummyData;
          var trendingNews = dataCtrl.isDataLoaded.value
              ? dataCtrl.trendingNews.value.data!.newsList!
              : dummyData;
          return Skeletonizer(
            enableSwitchAnimation: true,
            enabled: !dataCtrl.isDataLoaded.value,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              controller: ctrl.scrollController.value,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  SectionDivider(title: 'Featured', onSeeAll: () {}),
                  FeaturedCard(newsList: topStories),
                  const SizedBox(height: 15),
                  SectionDivider(title: 'News', onSeeAll: () {}),
                  const SizedBox(height: 10),
                  const TopicsChip(),
                  const SizedBox(height: 16),
                  //* First page being called from here*//
                  //****//
                  const NewsTile(newsList: trendingNews),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}


Page 1
A stateless widdget with getx state management

ListView.builder(
shrinkWrap: true,
itemCount: trendingNews.length,
physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
return nkWell(
    onTap: () => Get.to(ReadDetails(newsData: newsData)),
    child: Hero(
      tag: '${newsData.imageUrl!}as image tag',
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
        ),
        child: CachedNetworkImage(
          cacheKey: newsData.imageUrl,
          width: constraints.maxWidth * 0.4,
          height: constraints.maxHeight,
          placeholder: (_, __) => const MyShimmer(),
          errorWidget: (_, __, er) => const Icon(Icons.error),
          imageUrl: newsData.imageUrl!,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
 },
);


Page 2
Also a stateless widdget with getx state management
Stack(
    children: [
      Hero(
        tag: '${newsData.imageUrl!}as image tag',
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
          child: CachedNetworkImage(
            height: Get.size.height / 2.5,
            cacheKey: newsData.imageUrl!,
            imageUrl: newsData.imageUrl!,
            placeholder: (_, __) => const MyShimmer(),
            errorWidget: (_, __, er) => const Icon(Icons.error),
            width: Get.size.width,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Positioned(
        top: 4,
        left: 8,
        child: FloatingIconButton(
          onTap: () => Get.back(),
          icon: Icons.arrow_back_ios_new,
        ).animate().slide(delay: Durations.medium4),
      ),
    ],
  );

What I've Tried:

Added AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin to the NewsTile class: This didn't resolve the issue.

Added CachedNetworkImage.

Used unique Hero tags for each tile, based on the news item's id and imageUrl: The problem still persists.



you can remove getx and give a try
